# Problem building an url with argument

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I have tried to build an url using a parameter, and it depends on the element the user clicks.

I have used the method `add_query_arg( 'id',  $id, 'http://example.com' )`, and the href value of the anchor looks ok, but when I click it, wp redirects me to the url example.com, but the url looks like example.com/?id=1. Is this the expected behaviour? I don't know why is writing the slash character before the args.

Comment: Yes this is the expected behaviour. `example.com?id=1` is not a valid URL. What is it exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm triying to pass a parameter through the url to one page in my website to show the information about one item stored in the bd. As far as I know, the url should be something like www.example.com/show?id=1.

Comment: No, it would look like `example.com/show/?id=1`, as you can see [from the examples in the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/#user-contributed-notes)

Comment: Thanks Kero for your help!